# Web API 2 Routing Failing

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am experiencing problems with Web API 2 using Route Attributes.  I have been using them successfully for a bit now, but I have one that consistently returns a 404 error.  By the by, the controller has other methods which are working as expected.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/physicalschool")]
   public class PhysicalSchoolController : ApiController
   {
       [HttpGet]
       [Route("state/{stateId:int}/districts")]
       IEnumerable<PhysicalSchoolBasic> GetDistrictsByStateId([FromUri]int stateId)
       {
```

I am not sure why this is happening.  Maybe a set of fresh eyes will help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Here is one that is working:

```
[HttpGet]
    [Route("school/{groupId:int}/propertytypes")]
    public IEnumerable<PhysicalSchoolProperty> GetPhysicalSchoolTypes(int groupId = 0)
    {
```

It is on the same controller, and uses the same RoutePrefix.

Comment: Please provide more details. Can you show one of the methods that is working? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Comment: What is your request url? and also can you share how your central configuration of routes looks like?

Comment: I am overriding them them with the Route Attribute.  They are default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  I forgot to make the method public.

Answer (score 0):

Wow. I feel worthless. I just spent ~3 hours trying to find a similar issue on a new empty web app project with just the web api reference checkbox checked. Basically any entirely empty app. I created a new controller and put attribute routes on it. Just got 404s. Turns out, it was because my class was not marked public.